# Windows Groups in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

Are there method or external add-on software for Windows 7 operating system for creating windows groups? I want to group some windows including their current monitor, their sizes and their positions. When I click the group from start bar all windows of this groups reappear in saved positions.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this problem before. Go to your display settings under the control panel. Make sure you can see both monitors connected, there should be a one and two listed. Note that one that is listed as number 1. Make sure that your start menu and task bar is on monitor 1, then you should be able to do what you want to do.